# Angular 5 - date - language

Tags: date, internationalization, angular5

I use this expression in my Angular 5 application:

```
{{ viewDate | date:'MMM' }}
```

The month abbreviation is shown in English. How do I switch the output to German?

**[SOLVED]**
https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID

Answer (score 17):

As you already pointed out you have to define a locale within your app. The documentation for the [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) states

> Formats a date according to locale rules.

The pipe has to be used like so

```
{{ date_expression | date[:format[:timezone[:locale]]] }}
```

As you can see, the pipe accepts a `format`, `timezone` and `locale` parameter (besides the actual date that is to be parsed).
Reading further, documentation states

> `locale` is a string defining the locale to use (uses the current [LOCALE_ID](https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID) by default)

[Here's](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#i18n-pipes) a read up on how the `LOCALE` definition works.
You probably want to localize your entire application in German.
First, you want to import the German locales within your AppModule.

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import {LOCALE_ID, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
 
registerLocaleData(localeDe);
```

Now you can use the locale as usual

```
@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de'}]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Your initial expression `{{viewDate | date:'MMM'}}` should now output the german localized abbreviated month.