# Show the german dayname & right week number Angular

Tags: angular, date, format, devextreme

I've build a scheduler with dxScheduler. In want to display the name of the day in the dx-scheduler-header-row in german language.

I have localiced my application in germany.

So far I have:

```
<div *dxTemplate="let data of 'dateCellTemplate' let dataIndex = index">
        <div [ngClass]="getClassName(data)">
             <span>{{[data.date | date :'EEEE dd.MM [w]'}}</span>
         </div>
</div>
```

This shows me

Monday 22.04 [17] ;  Tuesday 23.04 [17]

and so on.

I want there

Montag 22.04 [17] ; Dienstag 23.04 [17]

EDIT:

With the solution I just solved the Monday => Montag issue.
But with the week Number it does not work!

Format: Day Date [Weeknumber]

Mo 29.04 [18] ... Sa 04.05 [18]  So 05.05 [19] <- ????

Why the weeknumber is here 19? It should be 18.

Comment: This is not `devextreme` related, but rather angular-related. You need to set the `date` pipe localization, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850214/angular-5-date-language . Devextreme has its own localization service, but since you're parsing dates using the angular pipes, you should localize angular's provider instead.

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for!

Comment: This solve the day-issue. But my Weeknumbers are false. It increments at Sunday not on Monday

Comment: This is because you need the ISO standard, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117814/get-week-of-year-in-javascript-like-in-php

Comment: Instead of <span>{{[data.date | date :'EEEE dd.MM [w]'}}</span>  i have now : <span >{{getWeekNumber(data.date)}}</span>

But this shows in each header cell the same week number (from the  last date in my view).. Any ideas?

I get an error: "Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'null: 19'. Current value: 'null: 21"

So in Week 19 it shows 21 and week 20 it shows 21 in week 21 it shows 21.

Comment: `getWeekNumber(data.date)` <-- this will update (too often) the value Expression. Avoid using method directly, define a **custom pipe** instead dealing with it, otherwise angular will not be able to render it properly due to the expression (result of the function, in that case) changing too often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @briosheje I've got the right way ToDO:

in **myComponent.component.html** I changed:

```html
<div *dxTemplate="let data of 'dateCellTemplate' let dataIndex = index">
        <div [ngClass]="getClassName(data)">
             <span>{{[data.date | date :'EEEE dd.MM [w]'}}</span>
         </div>
</div>
```

TO

```html
<div *dxTemplate="let data of 'dateCellTemplate' let dataIndex = index">
    <div [ngClass]="getClassName(data)">
        <span>{{[ data.date | date : '.MM' ]}}</span><br>
        <span>{{[ data.date | wochenNummer ]}}</span>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Where "wochenNummer" is the name of my Pipe.

Create the pipe

```
ng generate pipe WochenNummer
```

This create 2 Files

wochen-nummer.pipe.spec.ts
wochen-nummer.pipe.ts

In **wochen-nummer.pipe.ts** i have:

```
 export class WochenNummerPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: Date): string {
    // Copy date so don't modify original
    value = new Date(Date.UTC(value.getFullYear(), value.getMonth(), value.getDate()));
    // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
    // Make Sunday's day number 7
    value.setUTCDate(value.getUTCDate() + 4 - (value.getUTCDay() || 7));
    // Get first day of year
    const yearStart = new Date(Date.UTC( value.getUTCFullYear(), 0, 1));
    // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
    const weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (+value - +yearStart) / 86400000) + 1) / 7);
    // Return array of year and week number
    const returner = '[' + weekNo + ']';
    return returner;
  }

}
```

here I have my week number calculation. @briosheje postet a link above

To make things Work I had to include the pipe in the **myComponent.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [WochenNummerPipe],
  declarations: [
    ...  ,
    WochenNummerPipe
  ]
})
```

All together I got this: [picture of my header cell template with right week number and german daynames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM6ML.png)

I am happy :)